# Finding elements of one list in another in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `J1,J2`. I want to find elements of `J1` which are not in `J2`. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
J1=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]]
J2=[[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]]

J=[i for i in J1 not in J2]
print(J)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    J=[i for i in J1 not in J2]

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

The expected output is

```
J=[[1,4]]
```

Comment: `J1 not in J2` returns a boolean value. Your statement looks something like `J=[i for i in True]`.

Comment: `J = set(J1)-set(J2)`  In your case you have list of lists, so you should do `set(J1[0])-set(J2[0])`, but I don't see any reason for J1 and J2 to be list of lists and not just regular flat lists, so better change J1 and j2 to `J1=[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]` `J2=[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]`

Comment: `J=[i for i in J1[0] if i not in J2[0]]` this will output `[1,4]`

Comment: For some reason which is hard to understand you are using a List of a List; hence @Yash Mehta use of [0] to get the first (and only ) List element.

Comment: yes you are right but his question is contradict as you see in first line he return `I have two lists J1,J2.` not clearly mentioned `list of lists`.@user19077881

Comment: `J = [[x for x in J1[i] if x not in J2[i]] for i in range(len(J1))]` this will work fine though in list of lists @user19077881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking `J1` and `J2` as **list of lists** for better understanding.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

J1 = [[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10], [0, 2, 3, 1]]
J2 = [[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10], [1, 3, 5]]

J = [[x for x in J1[i] if x not in J2[i]] for i in range(len(J1))]

print(J)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 4], [0, 2]]
```